# Commit in Github

Tags: git, github, addition, git-commit

I use the following commands:

```
git add *
git commit -am 'updating'
```

And I encountered below:

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   webkomiks (modified content)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

What I am supposed to do?

I continued with:

```
git push myrep master
```

I only saw the folder in github not the files inside the folder.

thanks

Comment: Are you doing the `git add .` in the root directory of your project? Also, for tracked files, just `git commit -am"Updating"` is enough as the `-a` option adds all the tracked files.

Comment: yes, in the root directory. where it should be?

Comment: Actually - is webcomiks a submodule? You can check with the command `git submodule status` and if it shows up then it is a submodule.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't commit recursively into subdirectories.

Try `git add .` instead of `git add *`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that `webcomiks` is a submodule?

If so, then you need to go into the submodule directory, commit and push the changes that are in that submodule, and then go up to the main repository and commit from there.

Comment: i tried `git submodule status` and it says: No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'webkomiks'

Answer (score 0):

Is webkomiks a directory or a file or something else?

If you want to add webkomiks, as Johan Paul said, run 'git add webkomiks'

Try `git clean -n` and it should give you some more info.  If its a directory, it will say 'Would not remove'. Of course you can remove it by adding '`-d`' option.

Answer (score -1):

As the error message states:

```
 Changes not staged for commit:
 ...
 modified:   webkomiks (modified content)
```

That's probably a dir? That's not included in the commit. So do `git add webkomiks` and try again.

Comment: git doesn't know about directories, so it can't be a dir